# How can you run a rule against a different Store?

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

How can you run a rule against a different Store?

I can access my rules and execute them from the default store with ...

```
Set storeRules = Application.Session.DefaultStore.GetRules()
For Each storeRule In storeRules
    If storeRule.name = name Then
        storeRule.Execute ShowProgress:=True
    End If
Next
```

But I can't see how to use the rules against a shared account.

I can manually run through through the Outlook client, "Run Rules Now", and select the right folder in the "Run In Folder" browser

**UPDATE:**

Tried iterating through all my stores, and I have three stores. The ExchangeStoreType's are one 0- primary Exchange mailbox, one 2 - Exchange public folder (PF?) and one 1 - Exchange delegate mailbox. I'm trying to run the rules on the last one, but the `.GetRules` on the delegate folder doesn't find any rules

```
Sub RunTest()
Dim storeRules As Outlook.Rules
Dim storeRule As Outlook.Rule
Dim allStores As Outlook.stores
Dim myStore As Outlook.Store

Set allStores = Application.Session.stores
For Each myStore In allStores
    On Error Resume Next
    Debug.Print myStore.DisplayName & "  " & myStore.ExchangeStoreType
    Set storeRules = myStore.GetRules()
    For Each storeRule In storeRules
        Debug.Print "... store: " & storeRule.name
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

Yet I can run the rules if I go through the Outlook UI and select that store

Comment: Are you sure you are hitting the mailbox store, not PF?

Comment: Checking the ExchangeStoreType, I have three stores, one 0 - primary Exchange mailbox, one 2 - Exchange public folder (PF?) and one 1 - Exchange delegate mailbox. I want to run the rules against the delegate mailbox, but it doesn't have any rules???

Comment: Do yo use the rules in that store in OutlookSpy (go to the Inbox folder, click IMAPIFolder, PR_RULES_TABLE tab).

Comment: Nope ... OutlookSpy shows the rules tab against my Inbox, but not against the delegated Inbox

Comment: Does it make a difference if you turn caching off?

Comment: Err ... where do you turn off caching?

Comment: Uncheck "Use Cached Exchange Mode" in the Exchange account properties dialog.

Comment: No change ... the delegated store still has no rules, yet I can run my existing rules against it using the Outlook UI

Comment: Nothing on PR_RULES_TABLE tab in OutlookSpy?

Comment: Nope, the delegate inbox shows various tab, including a PR_ACL_TABLE, whereas my own inbox shows same set plus a PR_RULES_TABLE, and the table contains my rules

Comment: Then there is really nothing you can do, I am afraid...

Comment: Ah well ... thanks for all the help. I'm still intrigued as to how I can run the rules in the Outlook client, yet can't do similar in VBA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `Application.Session.DefaultStore`, use `Application.Session.Stores` collection to access the store in question.